# subsetting a list of list of strings without flattening

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
A = [['Computer Science', 'Gender- Male', 'Race Ethnicity- Hispanic', 'Race Ethnicity- White'],
    ['Computer Science', 'Gender- Female', 'Race Ethnicity- White'],
    ['History', 'Gender-Female', 'Race Ethnicity- Black'],
    ['Mechanical Engineering', 'Geder- Male', 'Race Ethnicity- American Indian or Alaskan Native', 'Race Ethnicity- Hispanic']]
```

I would like to only keep the elements that involve race and ethnicity. This is what I want to end up with:

```
B = [['Race Ethnicity- Hispanic', 'Race Ethnicity- White'],
    ['Race Ethnicity- White'],
    ['Race Ethnicity- Black'],
    ['Race Ethnicity- American Indian or Alaskan Native', 'Race Ethnicity- Hispanic']]
```

The following sort of works but doesn't keep the list of list structure

```
[y for x in test for y in x if "Race Ethnicity" in y]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're pretty close. Try:

```
[[y for y in x if 'Race' in y] for x in test]
```

The nested list comprehension will maintain your 2-dimensionality.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the result to be a list of lists, you should try a command in the form of `[[item for item in sublist if (condition)] for sublist in biglist]`.  Try this:

```
A = [['Computer Science', 'Gender- Male', 'Race Ethnicity- Hispanic', 'Race Ethnicity- White'],
    ['Computer Science', 'Gender- Female', 'Race Ethnicity- White'],
    ['History', 'Gender-Female', 'Race Ethnicity- Black'],
    ['Mechanical Engineering', 'Geder- Male', 'Race Ethnicity- American Indian or Alaskan Native', 'Race Ethnicity- Hispanic']]

print([ [info for info in student if "Race Ethnicity" in info] for student in A ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function `filter()` inside the listcomp:

```
[list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('Race'), i)) for i in A]
```